# Error while import keras: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_clear_session_function'

Tags: python, keras

I want to `import keras` after I did `pip install keras`, but it shows message as shown below. I even can't call any function from keras library. Can anyone know about this?

```
import keras
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_clear_session_function'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you  should use `import tensorflow.keras` instead of `import keras`.
More info [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15147).

Answer (score 3):

This can be caused by a version mismatch between Keras installation and Tensorflow. Make sure their versions match.

Answer (score 1):

after tf2, you should use

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

Comment: sorry，My fault，its tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install -U -q segmentation-models
!pip install -q tensorflow==2.1
!pip install -q keras==2.3.1
!pip install -q tensorflow-estimator==2.1.

## Imports libs
import os
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '0'
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"

from tensorflow import keras
import segmentation_models as sm
```

Comment: Why does she/he should install `segmentation-models` for importing keras?? Please provide a clear answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

None of the other answers here worked for me. I ended up updating keras and tensorflow as follows:

```
pip install --upgrade keras
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Now, it works for me.