# module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_clear_session_function'

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to import Keras in Jupyter Notebook and I got this error:

```
module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'register_clear_session_function'
```

Comment: Upgrade TensorFlow and Keras.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while import keras: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2.\_\_internal\_\_' has no attribute 'register\_clear\_session\_function'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68737130/error-while-import-keras-attributeerror-module-tensorflow-compat-v2-interna)

Answer (score 1):

You can update keras and tensorflow.
Or
Use `import tensorflow.keras` instead of `import keras`.